# Prevent collapsing when clicking sub-item in navigation

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have build a stacked navigation with several sub-menus.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#subnav">
    Nav
    <ul class="nav nav-pills collapse" id="subnav">
        <li><a href="#">Subnav1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subnav2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subnav3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When click on the parent, the sub-menus will open nicely. However, when I click on any of the sub-items, the parent menu will close again. How can I prevent this?

**Edit:** Try out on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/idleberg/5HbL3/)

Comment: Can you please post your JS code as well

Comment: Use fiddle to show us your problem. http://www.bootply.com/new

Comment: @YogeshSharma the JS for this is already built into bootstrap

Comment: aah, Ok got it, let me check your fiddle

Comment: You can use your custom functionality for toggle if you want I can create JS for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to extract the trigger element out of the collapsible...

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/t3zahILQ0r)**

**HTML** :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li>
    <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#subnav">Nav</span>   
    <ul class="nav nav-pills collapse" id="subnav">
        <li><a href="#">Subnav1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subnav2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subnav3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :

```
$("#subnav").on( "click.bs.collapse.data-api", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```